# Call SSIS Package on 2008 server from SQL Agent Job on remote 2005 server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, permissions, sql-agent

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to remotely execute an SSIS package.  The package resides on a SQL Server 2008 instance and I'd like to call it from a Job on a 2005 server. The error I'm getting is:

> The package could not be loaded.  The
>   step failed.

If I go from 2008 to 2008, there is no error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're attempting to execute the package with a `dtexec` command, the issue is that the package is executed on the calling server, not the server where it is stored.

Since the 2005 SSIS service can't execute 2008 packages, the step fails.

You need to trigger the `dtexec` on the server where you want the job to run. The easiest way to do this is probably to set up a SQL Agent job on the 2008 server which starts the package, and trigger that from the 2005 server (using sp_startjob or some more complex trigger mechanism).

Comment: Ed, thanks, the wording of the message sounds very obvious now that you mention it.  Is there a way to trigger a job on a remote server without using Linked Servers?

Comment: @Traples - there are lots of ways. For example, you could use a scheduled SSIS package on the 2005 box which connects to the 2008 machine to start the job there. Alternatively, you could use a trigger mechanism outside SQL server (like a batch file running SQLCMD). It depends quite a lot on what the other constraints on your environment are.

Answer (score 1):

Does the account your are running under have permissions on the SQL 2005 box. You can create a proxy under which to run the job.