# Execute SSIS package from remote server

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a sql job and a package on server named ssis.  I would like to call either that package or that job from a stored procedure on server named storedProcedureServer and return the results of the package execution back to the stored proc for further processing.

Question:  Can I still use msdb.dbo.sp_start_job and execute the job on the remote box?  Or do I have to create ssis1 as a linked server and execute it via the link?  Or is there another option that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,
please take a look at these two posts:

[Execute SQL Server SSIS Package From Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/923195/327165),
[Call SSIS Package on 2008 server from SQL Agent Job on remote 2005 server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3104159/327165)

> do I have to create ssis1 as a linked server and execute it via the link?

this may be an easiest solution.

> return the results of the package execution back to the stored proc for further processing

sp_start_job just starts a job, your sp will not wait for job/package to finish. You may need to come up with extra logic that checks for remote package completion.